# Does there exist a smallest possible rational number?

Tags: real-analysis

I was absent from my Analysis Class for a couple days, and I'm a bit confused as to how to solve this problem... any help would be appreciated!

Does there exist a smallest possible rational number?
Given a real number x, does there exist a smallest real number y > x?

From C.C Pugh - Real Mathematical Analysis

Comment: I think you've asked two different questions. Pay careful attention to the use of 'rational' and 'real'

Comment: Given a positive rational number, you can always divide by two to get a smaller one.

Comment: Do you understand the problem? Think of any rational number (say, $-5/12$), is there any rational number that is _less_ than the number you thought of? Apply the same reasoning to the other question.

Comment: Make sure you talk to your professor; they more than anybody will be able to help you catch up.

Comment: Note that $n+1 > n$, so what is the relationship between $1/n$ and $1/(n+1)$? What does this tell you about rational numbers in general?

Comment: The first part of the problem was inquiring about real numbers. I said dividing by two could always get a smaller real number.

Comment: Will the same exact proof work for rational numbers as well? I feel like there's a trick I'm missing. 

As for the second part of the problem, I'm not a 100% sure what it's asking and how it differs from the other parts.

Comment: Definitely Matthew! I'll go to his office hours asap :) I just didn't want to be too behind for lecture tomorrow...